# Remix Metamask doesnt switch address

Tags: solidity, metamask, remix

Helloo everyone

I have the following problem: I am deploying a contract in remix that has a function that cannot be called from the deployer address. I have a selling contract, the deployer address is the seller the purchase function cannot be called by him, because the seller cannot buy from himself. I deploy the contract in address X, than I switch to address Y and click the button purchase and the contract says "The seller cannot buy from himself!". In the Javascript VM everything works perfectly, problem is only injected web3 metamask. The same mistake bug comes in https in chrome and in http in firefox. Firefox only deploys this contract with one given address, with the other ones it does not deploy and displays in the terminal: "creation of purchase errored: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address."

I tried both rinkeby and kovan testnet.

Thank you very much in advance for any type of help!

this is the contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6;
contract purchase{
    address payable public seller;
    address payable public buyer;
    address public shipper;
    uint public bonifico_min;
    uint private refund;
    enum StatusType {Start,Paid,Accepted}
    StatusType public status;

    constructor(address s, uint min){
        seller=payable(msg.sender);
        status = StatusType.Start;
        shipper = s;
        bonifico_min=min;
    }

    function propose_and_pay() public payable{
        require((status==StatusType.Start)&& (msg.value>=bonifico_min));
        require(msg.sender!=seller, "The seller cannot buy from himself!");
        buyer=payable(msg.sender);
        status=StatusType.Paid;

    } 
    function reject() public{ 
        require(msg.sender==seller);
        require(status==StatusType.Paid);
        status = StatusType.Start;
    }
    function accept() public{
        require(msg.sender==seller);
        require(status==StatusType.Paid);
        status = StatusType.Accepted;
    }
    function delivered() public{
        require(status==StatusType.Accepted);
        require(msg.sender==shipper);
        status = StatusType.Start;
        seller.transfer( (address(this)).balance );
    }
    function not_delivered() public{
        require(status==StatusType.Accepted);
        require(msg.sender==shipper);
        status = StatusType.Start;
        buyer.transfer( (address(this)).balance );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the following:

1. You have given access to Remix all of your Metamask accounts(which you want to switch). If you are not sure, then disconnect the Remix from Metamask...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcf6W.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFXSJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G78p9.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVuQO.png

2. Select Injected web3-Metamask
3. You have to switch account in Metamask rather than in Remix, and it will be switched in Remix automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with a contract, you should be setting multiple accounts for multiple purposes: for example one for contract owner or one for buyer etc. Then in order to swtich account, you should be opening metamask while you are on remix.

[image]

You should manually switch accounts

Answer (score 0):

One more way to try, which worked for me -

1. Take the backup of your code & remove all the files from your Remix workspace.
2. Completely clear the workspace & reload the remix page.
3. Create new file/s & paste the code in them.
4. Compile the code & now try to switch the Environment to Metamask.